# How to refresh angular page after x minutes without user interaction?

Tags: angular, refresh

I have an Angular 7 application. It shows different statuses which change irregulary by the time. I want to update my component (reload it) after every 5 minutes but **only if there was no user interaction** in the last 2 minutes.

Is there a way to do so with Angular?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Tried to use setInterval()?

Comment: I can use this to reload it periodically, but how to check whether the user interacted with the page last time?

Comment: Added a solution for this as you can see below.

Comment: You should have a global var that gets updated (`this.globalVar = new Date()`) everytime something is clicked (if you mean that with user-interaction). Every five minutes, with a setInterval, just check the date diff between now and the global var and you're up to go.

Answer (score 0):

In your top level component, create an observable from an event of a Document object and invoke your service, for example:

```
const clicks = Observable.fromEvent(document, 'click');
clicks.subscribe(x => console.log('Calling my service here'));
```